# Storage of values?

Tags: android

I have a database with 4 tables. Each table has 1 column. 3 of the tables will typically hold only around 8-12 values, the other maybe 100+. The values are basic, color, city, etc. The user clicks a button, up pops a list with values they can select, delete or add.

It seems like a lot to have a table for ~8 values. I was wondering if there was a better way to store this data given that values need to be able to be added, deleted and the number will be dynamic.

Comment: Your setup seems logical to me. What are you using, sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not trying to turn you off of using sqlite, but just to put down some other options.

They are, direct from the [Data Storage Developer doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html):

1. Shared Preferences
2. Internal Storage
3. External Storage
4. Network Server

I would recommend either Shared Preferences or Internal Storage for such a small amount of values.  Performance wise, my understanding is you will get better performance using one of these two but I would get confirmation, I'm just repeating what I've heard at SO before.  For such a small amount of values, I'm not certain that the difference is even measurable or will have any effect on your app.